# Laravel pagination won't work properly on virtual machine

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade, laravel-pagination

I'm using Laravel's default pagination functionality. In this case, the pagination is supposed to get triggered when the records that are returned are more than 10 records. For some reason, this functionality completely works fine on my local machine as seen here:

**LOCAL MACHINE**
[image: Local machine pagination 1]

[image: Local machine pagination 2]

As you can see, after filtering the data, there are more than 10 results and when I go to page 2, it shows the rest of the results based on the filter.

For some reason when I try this on my virtual machine running windows 10, similar environment and all, the outcome is quite different as seen here:

**VIRTUAL MACHINE**
[image: Virtual machine pagination 1]
[image: Virtual machine pagination 2]

As you can notice, the page 1 works fine, but when I click page 2, the search filter is like completely disregarded and just starts showing all the other pages. The code is exactly the same on both my local machine and the virtual machine, the environment is same as well.

This is the code inside the 'search' function in my controller that's responsible for returning the records and handling the pagination:

```
$finalResults = $results->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

return view('customers.index',['customers' => $finalResults])
            ->with('subscriptions',Subscription::all())
            ->with('users', User::all())
            ->with($request->session()->flash('info', $results->count() . ' record(s) were found from your search.'));
```

And this is the code on the index page responsible for displaying the pagination buttons, it's pretty standard:

```
<div class="col-12">{{$customers->links()}}</div>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I'd be glad to provide more info if necessary and would also be glad for any insight regarding this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you problem is not based on environment. I think your pagination links are failing to add get parameters. So try the below Code

```
$finalResults = $results->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10)->appends(request()->all());

return view('customers.index',['customers' => $finalResults])
            ->with('subscriptions',Subscription::all())
            ->with('users', User::all())
            ->with($request->session()->flash('info', $results->count() . ' record(s) were found from your search.'));
```